# Set some properties of red5

Tags: red5

m getting error while setting these properties of red. Does anybody here knows how to set them in red5.properties.

```
        <property name="eventThreadsCore" value="${rtmp.event_threads_core}" />
        <property name="eventThreadsMax" value="${rtmp.event_threads_max}" />
        <property name="eventThreadsQueue" value="${rtmp.event_threads_queue}" />
        <property name="eventThreadsKeepalive" value="${rtmp.event_threads_keepalive}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to set them. They are already setted down the file. Just dont copy them into another class's defination. Btw if u want to change values `rtmp.event_threads_core` they are in `red5.properties` in `red5-0.9.1/conf/war` folder.